# what is the difference between version 1.0 and version 3.2 in corda

Tags: corda

List out differences between 1.0 and 3.2 version in corda .how to upgrade corda from version 1.0 to 3.2 using intellij

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the [documentation](http://docs.corda.net):

Release notes: https://docs.corda.net/release-notes.html

Upgrade Notes: https://docs.corda.net/upgrade-notes.html